# Adding Git Bash Alias

Tags: git, bash, alias, git-bash

I have created an alias for this `git diff --stat origin/master`.

The alias for this is

```
[alias]
  dp = "!DIFF_PREVIEW=$(git diff --stat origin/master HEAD);"
```

When I run `dp`, Git Bash works, but it does not show anything in the terminal window.
If I type `git diff --stat origin/master`, it actually shows my commits in the terminal window.

How can I modify my alias so it reproduces this as well?

Comment: You're using a command substitution to save the output of that Git command to a variable called `DIFF_PREVIEW`; that's why running `git dp` prints nothing. Why are you doing that? Are you using the value of `DIFF_PREVIEW` at all?

Comment: No I am not. I thought you had to do it this way

Answer (score 3):

Just

```
[alias]
  dp = diff --stat origin/master HEAD
```

should work.

Comment: That does work but it shows me every single commit. How can I modify it so it just shows my commits?

Comment: @user3259232 It's hard to do with diff, you may use `git log -p --author=you@example.com`.

Comment: @user3259232 What do you mean by "it shows me every single commit"? `git diff` compares *two* commits, those corresponding to `origin/master` and `HEAD`, here. Those are the only two commits that your command will tell you about... Moreover, please don't "move the goalpost" by adding new, unrelated requirements in the comments. Either edit your question or ask a new question, if you have to.